# How to get all data I have Inserted?

Tags: json, scala, reactivemongo

I have made a small app using json and reactiveMongo which inserts
Students Information.

```
object Applications extends Controller{

  val studentDao = StudentDaoAndEntity
  val studentqueryReader: Reads[JsObject] = implicitly[Reads[JsObject]]

  def saveStudent = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[StudentInfo].map {
      k => studentDao.insertStudent(k).map {
        l => Ok("Successfully inserted")
      }
    }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest("Invalid Json"))
```

**In databse**

```
object StudentDaoAndEntity {

  val sreader: Reads[StudentInfo] = Json.reads[StudentInfo]
  val swriter: Writes[StudentInfo] = Json.writes[StudentInfo]
  val studentqueryReader: Reads[JsObject] = implicitly[Reads[JsObject]]

  def db = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db
  def collection: JSONCollection = db[JSONCollection]("student")
  def insertStudent(student: StudentInfo): Future[JsObject]= {   
    val modelToJsObj = swriter.writes(student).as[JsObject]
    collection.insert(modelToJsObj) map (_ => modelToJsObj)
  }
```

This works fine. Now I need to get all data I have inserted. How can I
   do that? I am not asking for code but for Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: it seems that you are using [Play-ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html) (as far as i know, `JSONCollection` is not part of ReactiveMongo itself). If this is the case, then your code is unnecessarily complex. Instead of doing the JSON conversions manually, you just can pass your `StudentInfo` objects directly to `insert`. Minimal example:

```
val studentInfo: StudentInfo = ...
def collection: JSONCollection = db[JSONCollection]("student")
collection.insert(studentInfo)
```

That's the elegant part of the Play plugin. Yes, MongoDB persists data as JSON (or BSON, to be more precise), but you don't have do deal with it. Just make sure the implicit `Writes` (or `Reads`, in case of querying) is in scope, as well as other necessary imports (e.g. `play.modules.reactivemongo.json._`).

---

> Now I need to get all data I have inserted. How can I do that? I am
>   not asking for code but for Idea.

Well, you want to have a look at the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html) (scroll down for examples), it's quite simple and there is not more to it. In your case, it could look like this:

```
// perform query via cursor
val cursor: Cursor[StudentInfo] =
     collection.find(Json.obj("lastName" -> "Regmi")).cursor[StudentInfo]

// gather results as list
val futureStudents: Future[List[StudentInfo]] = cursor.collect[List]()
```

In this case, you get all students with the last name *Regmi*. If you really want to retrieve all students, then you probably need to pass an empty `JsObject` as your query. Again, it's not necessary to deal with JSON conversions, as long as the implicit `Reads` is in scope.

Comment: def findByLastName(lastname:String)=Action.async{
    val cursor=Json.obj("lastname"->Json.obj("lastname"->"Regmi"))
    StudentDaoAndEntity.findFirstStudent(cursor) map
      {
      case None=> Ok("Student Not Found")
      case Some(l)=> Ok(Json.toJson(l))
    }
  }

Comment: Yes  it works . But I want to get all students.I tried by passing empty Jsobject but it didnt work.

Comment: def findAll=Action.async {
    val cursor = Json.obj(" "-> " ")
    StudentDaoAndEntity.findAllStudent(cursor) map {
      case Nil => Ok("Student Not Found")
      case l:Seq[JsObject] => Ok(Json.toJson(l))
    }
  }

Comment: I have tried the above code to pass empty Jsobject.Can you please correct me?

Comment: def findAllStudent(allStd: JsObject): Future[Seq[JsObject]] = {
    // gather all the JsObjects in a list
    collection.find(allStd).cursor[JsObject].collect[List]()
  }

Comment: Using `.collect` on a whole collection is only appropriate for testing or if the number of docs is predicable (and not too high according that predication)

Answer (score 0):

- Here is the Complete Answer of my own Question

package controllers

def findAll=Action.async {

```
val cursor = Json.obj()

StudentDaoAndEntity.findAllStudent(cursor) map {

  case Nil => Ok("Student Not Found")

  case l:Seq[JsObject] => Ok(Json.toJson(l))
}
```

}

def findAllStudent(allStd: JsObject): Future[Seq[JsObject]] = {

```
// gather all the JsObjects in a list

collection.find(allStd).cursor[JsObject].collect[List]()
```

}